# How do I apply a bold to first LI elements in nested structure

Tags: css, css-selectors

I thought something like:

```
#list li > a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

But this applies to every LI anchor I want only the top level items to be boldified not nested LI's in LI's -- if this makes any sense?? :)

EDIT |

```
  <ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#">A</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">B</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">G</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">H</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a bit more specificity to your selector:

`#list > li > a`

This targets any `a` that is a direct descendent of an `li` that is a direct descendent of `#list` (which I'm assuming is the outer `ul`, even though that's not specified in your example).

You can see it in action at http://jsbin.com/segig/1/edit?css,output.

No extra markup or rules necessary, which makes this a pretty clean solution.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for :) I had all but given up...CSS is not interesting enough to me to spend a whole evening pulling my hair out -- thanks for the answer Morgan!

Comment: Glad I could help keep your code clean and your links bold! :)

Comment: Clean code is huge but at this stage its more about bragging rights :p so again thank you haha

Answer (score 1):

### This can be done using CSS

---

The concept you are looking for is called pseudo element or CSS selectors

- Try using `first-line` instead of `first-child`

---

#### ANSWER:

#### JSBIN

**http://jsbin.com/dogol/1/edit**

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
<ul>
    <li class="ml"><a href="#">A</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">B</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="ml"><a href="#">F</a></li>
    <li  class="ml"><a href="#">G</a></li>
    <li class="ml" ><a href="#">H</a></li>
  </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.ml:first-line
{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: But this still requires me to add a class "ml" to individual top-most LI elements -- what is the difference between that or just having a class "ml" with bold? I'm missing something :s

Comment: Yes, there are differences.... if you don't use css pseudo elements, the css properties you set for that item will be followed by all list elements, and since you want to filter only first line elements you should use `first-line` selector ...

Comment: Pardon me -- but my CSS learning stopped at version 1 haha...I have applied a class "topmost" to each of the top most LI elements and selected like (#list li.topmost { font-weight: bold; }) and this still isn't working :s

Comment: by not working I mean the bold effect is being applied to all LI's still...is this what your solution addresses?

Comment: @Alex.Barylski It's okay... Next time please copy all important codes...so that we may understand/help you better....You said You wanted to Bold A,F,G,H ....and I provided the solution...

Comment: @Alex.Barylski can you explain how is the another answer is different from mine :)

Comment: I accepted "YourFriend" answer only because they answered first and basically told me what I needed to hear -- whether or not the cascading effect could be overridden without explicitly using classes, etc...I thought CSS had the ability to say "apply style only to immediate child elements of a given type whilst excluding grand-children" -- I have googled to the end of earth and it appears as though this is not directly supported. This is ultimately what I was trying to answer. HTH

Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Pseudo-elements are not the appropriate solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can stop the cascading effect of the css, so you'd have to specify the class as you go along. 
[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4vW26/1/)

HTML:

```
            <ul class="first">
                <li><a href="#">A</a>
                    <ul class="innerfirst">
                        <li><a href="#">B</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">G</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">H</a></li>
              </ul>
```

CSS:

```
            .first {
              font-weight: bold;

            }

            .innerfirst {
                font-weight: normal;
            }
```

Comment: This is the last resort option I am considering...I was hoping you could express "Apply to only immediate children" or "apply to all children except children of children" using the *not* operator or whatever its called in CSS context :p